# Web analytics stopped working

Tags: web-analytics

I have a site collection for which web analytics was working fine.
Recently, It stopped working and I get below error on the web analytics page:

*There are no addresses available for this application. 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEndpointAddressNotFoundException: There are no addresses available for this application.*

I checked the Web analytic Service application is running (Status=Started).
Any idea what may be the problem?

Comment: Does your ULS Log show anything more specific when you access the page or when the service runs?

Comment: @MichaelF, I did not find more info in ULS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to stopped services.

Go to Central Administration>System Settings>Manage services on server. On this page, ensure that below services are started :

- Web Analytics Data Processing Service
- Web Analytics Web Service

Answer (score -2):

If it doesn't work, you may have to stop and start the Managed Metadata Service , please check this for more info:
http://sp-vinod.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/failed-to-get-server-time-zone-id.html

Comment: Please give the answer here. By all means link to your blog for reference, but don't forget to mention that it is your own blog.